# Split lines into paragraphs

Tags: python

Input: a list of lines

Output: a list of list of lines, which is the input list split at (sequences of one or more) empty lines.

This is the least ugly solution I have so far:

```
split_at_empty(lines):
    paragraphs = []
    p = []
    def flush():
        if p:
            paragraphs.append(p)
        p = []
    for l in lines:
        if l:
            p.append(l)
        else:
            flush()
    flush()
    return paragraphs
```

There must be a better solution (perhaps even functional)! Anyone?

Sample input list:

```
['','2','3','','5','6','7','8','','','11']
```

Output:

```
[['2','3'],['5','6','7','8'],['11']]
```

Comment: Post a sample of your input list.

Comment: @Jo So Your "solution" doesn't work: local ``p`` in ``flush()`` is responsible of ``UnboundLocalError: local variable 'p' referenced before assignment``. That's not serious

Comment: @eyquem. My bad. Was too much in a JavaScript mood. To have it work, we must make it even a bit uglier.

Comment: @Jo So OK, you are a fair guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

ss =  '''Princess Maria Amelia of Brazil (1831–1853)


was the daughter of Dom Pedro I,
founder of Brazil's independence and its first emperor,

and Amelie of Leuchtenberg.



The only child from her father's second marriage,
Maria Amelia was born in France
following Pedro I's 1831 abdication in favor of his son Dom Pedro II.

Before Maria Amelia was a month old, Pedro I left for Portugal
to restore its crown to his eldest daughter Dona Maria II.
He defeated his brother Miguel I (who had usurped Maria II's throne),
only to die a few months later of tuberculosis.


'''

def select_lines(input,regx = re.compile('((?:^.+\n)+)',re.MULTILINE)):
    return [x.splitlines() for x in regx.findall(input)]

for sl in  select_lines(ss):
    print sl
    print
```

result

```
['Princess Maria Amelia of Brazil (1831\x961853)']

['was the daughter of Dom Pedro I,', "founder of Brazil's independence and its first emperor,"]

['and Amelie of Leuchtenberg.']

["The only child from her father's second marriage,", 'Maria Amelia was born in France', "following Pedro I's 1831 abdication in favor of his son Dom Pedro II."]

['Before Maria Amelia was a month old, Pedro I left for Portugal', 'to restore its crown to his eldest daughter Dona Maria II.', "He defeated his brother Miguel I (who had usurped Maria II's throne),", 'only to die a few months later of tuberculosis.']

[['2', '3'], ['5', '6', '7', '8'], ['11']]
```

Another way, to act on lists:

```
li = [ '', '2', '3', '', '5', '6', '7', '8', '', '', '11']

lo = ['5055','','','2','54','87','','1','2','5','8','','']

lu = ['AAAAA','BB','','HU','JU','GU']

def selines(L):
    ye = []
    for x in L:
        if x:
            ye.append(x)
        elif ye:
            yield ye ; ye = []
    if ye:
        yield ye



for lx in (li,lo,lu):
    print lx
    print list(selines(lx))
    print
```

result

```
['', '2', '3', '', '5', '6', '7', '8', '', '', '11']
[['2', '3'], ['5', '6', '7', '8'], ['11']]

['5055', '', '', '2', '54', '87', '', '1', '2', '5', '8', '', '']
[['5055'], ['2', '54', '87'], ['1', '2', '5', '8']]

['AAAAA', 'BB', '', 'HU', 'JU', 'GU']
[['AAAAA', 'BB'], ['HU', 'JU', 'GU']]
```

Comment: Maybe that's the best one! Using generators makes it cleaner, thanks.

Comment: This is now way to long and clumsy to be an accepted answer. Please edit it to be short and concise and you'll get back the accept :)

Comment: @Jo So Hello, I've considered your remark closely. I corrected the above code 2 days ago. Today I've also corrected other answers of mine. Because you're right, I tend to write too long answers. And I even deleted the comments I had written just here above, there's no interest to encumber stackoverflow's memories with these useless remarks of mine. Thank you to have pointed my flaw, I will remind that

Answer (score 2):

A bit less ugly than the original:

```
def split_at_empty(lines):
    r = [[]]
    for l in lines:
        if l:
            r[-1].append(l)
        else:
            r.append([])
    return [l for l in r if l]
```

(The last line gets rid of empty lists that would otherwise be added.)

Comment: Not bad, really! and the overhead is ok.

Comment: I rather like the simplicity of this one.  Only issue is if the input list is huge.

Answer (score 1):

And for list comprehension obsessives...

```
def split_at_empty(L):
    return [L[start:end+1] for start, end in zip(
        [n for n in xrange(len(L)) if L[n] and (n == 0 or not L[n-1])],
        [n for n in xrange(len(L)) if L[n] and (n+1 == len(L) or not L[n+1])]
        )]
```

or better

```
def split_at_empty(lines):
    L = [i for i, a in enumerate(lines) if not a]
    return [lines[s + 1:e] for s, e in zip([-1] + L, L + [len(lines)]) 
            if e > s + 1]
```

Comment: The first one is wrong unfortunately. The second one is nice but doesn't play nice with list generators.

Comment: both work for me with the original sample input (and others). What input list are you using?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, but it's a little confusing to have `L` and `lines` with different indices. Also, easier to read `L[n] and not L[n+1]` than `L[n] != '' and L[n + 1] == ''`.

Comment: (Maybe you want to except my changes)

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the list into a string and then resplit it:

```
>>> a = ['', '2', '3', '', '5', '6', '7', '8', '', '', '11']
>>> [x.strip().split(' ') for x in ' '.join(a).split('  ')]
[['2', '3'], ['5', '6', '7', '8'], ['11']]
```

And you should probably use a regex to catch any amount of whitespace (I added another one before the '11' here):

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')
>>> a = ['', '2', '3', '', '5', '6', '7', '8', '', '', '', '11']
>>> [x.strip().split(' ') for x in pat.split(' '.join(a))]
[['2', '3'], ['5', '6', '7', '8'], ['11']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generator-based solution:

```
def split_at_empty(lines):
   sep = [0] + [i for (i,l) in enumerate(lines) if not l] + [len(lines)]
   for start, end in zip(sep[:-1], sep[1:]):
      if start + 1 < end:
         yield lines[start+1:end]
```

For your input:

```
l = ['' , '2' , '3' , '' , '5' , '6' , '7' , '8' , '' , '' , '11']
for para in split_at_empty(l):
   print para
```

it yields

```
['2', '3']
['5', '6', '7', '8']
['11']
```

Comment: I had thought of this one, but don't you think it's a bit complicated and has too much overhead and long lines for the sole benefit of having few lines?